# Logic Unification of Skolem Functions

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, unification, first-order-logic

I've looked everywhere for any information I could find at all on this topic but I couldn't find anything. Even my textbook skipped over it entirely.

What are the rules regarding unification of Skolem functions, or even functions in general?

```
For example, can functions unify with constants?
Can R(f(x)) unify with R(A), where A is some constant? 
Every example I've seen has been of the form R(f(x)) unifying with R(y)
or R(f(x) unifying with R(f(A)) which are all pretty obvious. 

The example that really stumped me came from a solution to a resolution problem
in my Textbook, where they resolved the statement 




Rel(Parent, P(x,y),x) ∧ Rel(Parent, P(x,y), y) ∧ x != y ⇒ Rel(Sibling,Me,y)

with 

Rel(Parent, FM, Me)

to get 

Rel(Parent,FM,y) ⇒ Me != y ⇒ Rel(Sibling,Me,y)

Where P(x,y) is a skolem function and FM is a skolem constant representing the 
Father of Me


I understand the substitution of x = ME, but I don't understand how P(x,y) 
unified with FM.
```

Can anyone shed some insight?

Comment: this is probably a better fit for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's unification under an equational theory. Getting this right is hard and if you try a general definition of unification under equational constraints you can easily fall into undecidability. I did not quite get all the steps in your example on first read, so can't tell if everything else is right besides that. However for an informal argument it is ok.